# taking attribute (zip code) and using it in Google maps API 3

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have a magento site where my products are businesses.
I want to add a google map to the product page and need someone to help me with my code.

I can call the zip code by typing

```
<?php echo $_product->getpostcode() ?>
```

I have taken code from the internet and am trying to put it together for my site. here is the code:

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

   <script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address = '<?php echo $_product->getpostcode() ?>'
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
      }
    </script>
    <body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
```

At the moment it is using the lat long in the code. How can i change it to using the zip code?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps *always* use co-ordinates. That how maps work. If you want to use a zipcode, you need to convert that to co-ordinates — that process is called **geocoding**.

You have a geocoding function in your code, which won't work at the moment because you don't have an element called `address`, but it can be used with a little adjustment.

You currently have a global variable called `address`, which contains your zipcode, so get your geocoder function to use it:

At the bottom of function `initialize()`, add a call to the geocoder function, passing it the global variable:

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
 codeAddress(address);
}
```

Change that function to accept a parameter:

```
function codeAddress(addy) {
```

and then to use it:

```
// var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
// The above line needs to be removed; the one below amended
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addy}, function(results, status) {
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, how can I add the address to the global variable? at the moment i can obtain the zip code by entering this command <?php echo $_product->getpostcode() ?>   I followed your instructions and at the moment that map is showing sydney. I assume that is from the long and lat figures in my code

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/acleach/73Pf6/ (uses a London postcode instead of whatever your PHP outputs). The geocoding will either work and reset the map correctly, or it will output a failure message and show the `mapOptions` location, which is indeed Sydney.

Comment: Hi Andrew,looks like i am getting there. It also works for me when i manually enter the zip code. AS i mentioned before, i will be getting the zip code from the php echo command. I now need to put that into the var address. When i try to do that, i get Geocode was not successful for the following reason Zero_results

Comment: That means that whatever the browser is seeing in this line `var address = '<?php echo $_product->getpostcode() ?>'` is not a valid address. Use **View Source** in the browser and see what you're getting. You probably need to accept this answer (because it's right!) and ask another about getting `getpostcode()` working.

Comment: looking at view source i see var address = 'EC1 1TG'
looks like it is passing it through but still giving me the error

Comment: `EC1 1TG` is not a valid UK postcode, so `ZERO_RESULTS` is expected. Royal Mail have a [postcode checker](http://www.royalmail.com/postcode-finder?campaignid=postcodes_redirect) -- use "Find an Address".

Comment: Got it working. Just tested it out myself. it was a dummy post code entry. i entered a valid one and it started working. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

```
//i have working function use it.
  function initialize() {
var address = "<?php echo $address?>";
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.317408,11.12915);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("location-canvas"), myOptions);
if (geocoder) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
            });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map, 
            title:address
        }); 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

      } else {
        alert("Address Not found");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

}